# Why does \pdfpageattr not center its boxes?

Tags: pdftex, margins, geometry, bleed

Some printer services dictate to add a 3mm bleeding margin around the document in order to achieve marginless printing. I tried to use the `pdfpageattr` command to achieve that for my A4 document:

```
\pdfpageattr{
/MediaBox [0.0 0.0 612.283 858.898]
/BleedBox [0.0 0.0 612.283 858.898]
/CropBox [0.0 0.0 595.274 841.888]
/TrimBox [0.0 0.0 595.274 841.888]
}
```

This resizes the page as intended, however, the Trim and Crop boxes align to the left-bottom corner of the media/bleedbox. I.e., the media/bleed box are 6mm higher *at the top* and 6mm wider *on the right* of the page, instead of 3mm *on each site* (as I would expect).

How to change this alignment?
By the way, is there any documentation for these commands?

Comment: The "0.0 0.0" arguments are the coordinates of the lower left point of the boxes. You probably want to change some of these to be 8.504 (the number of big points in 3mm), or maybe -8.504, depending what you are trying to achieve. Also the other arguments are the top right point of the boxes, not the size of the boxes, so some of those are probably 8.504 off as well.

Comment: Hm, that makes sense now. I found that the first two numbers crop the trimbox, instead of moving its position. But since the other two numbers denote the other corners - and not the width/height - I can see how to center the box. Please make your comment an answer and provide a link to a documentation of that command. Thanks!

Comment: Any answe for this???

Comment: The first comment already solved the problem. Unfortunatelly, @alephzero has not created an answer.